# Failed to initialize clustered Vert.x

Tags: vert.x, infinispan

it can run on idea IDE , but when I generate a runnable jar file, and run it on a windows CMD window, it failed:

```
INFO [vert.x-worker-thread-0] CONTAINER - ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Taedonggang' 12.1.7.Final
INFO [vert.x-worker-thread-0] CONTAINER - ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller 'org.infinispan.commons.marshall.ImmutableProtoStreamMarshaller'
INFO [vert.x-worker-thread-0] CLUSTER - ISPN000078: Starting JGroups channel ISPN with stack jgroups
WARN [vert.x-worker-thread-0] Configurator - JGRP000014: STABLE.stability_delay has been deprecated: always 0
INFO [vert.x-worker-thread-0] GMS - PC-JiangZhiBing-64711: no members discovered after 2005 ms: creating cluster as coordinator
INFO [vert.x-worker-thread-0] CLUSTER - ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ISPN: [PC-JiangZhiBing-64711|0] (1) [PC-JiangZhiBing-64711]
INFO [vert.x-worker-thread-0] CLUSTER - ISPN000079: Channel ISPN local address is PC-JiangZhiBing-64711, physical addresses are [192.168.75.1:7800]
ERROR [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] VertxImpl - Failed to initialize clustered Vert.x
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.infinispan.factories.impl.ComponentRef.running()" because the return value of "org.infinispan.factories.impl.BasicComponentRegistry.getComponent(java.lang.Class)" is null
        at org.infinispan.counter.EmbeddedCounterManagerFactory.asCounterManager(EmbeddedCounterManagerFactory.java:35)
        at io.vertx.ext.cluster.infinispan.InfinispanClusterManager.lambda$join$6(InfinispanClusterManager.java:275)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$null$0(ContextImpl.java:159)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.AbstractContext.dispatch(AbstractContext.java:100)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$1(ContextImpl.java:157)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
INFO [vert.x-worker-thread-1] DefaultCacheManager - Stopping cache manager null on PC-JiangZhiBing-64711
INFO [vert.x-worker-thread-1] CLUSTER - ISPN000080: Disconnecting JGroups channel ISPN
```

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <configuration>
              <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                      <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                  </transformers>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
```

the version is <vertx.version>4.2.5</vertx.version>

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

oh ,when I read the Vertx doc from :https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-infinispan/java/

problem has been soled ,after add some line to maven plugin :

```
<transformers>
             <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
               
               <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
             </transformer>
             <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
           </transformers>
```